# What does うえ mean in this case？

Tags: meaning

What does うえ mean in this case：

実行委員会によりますと、この冬は極端に気温が上がる日がなかった**うえ**、十分な量の雪も確保できたことで、雪像作りは順調に進んだということです。

Answer (score 3):

It means "in addition to" in that context.

> 「Phrase A + 上{うえ}（or 上に） + Phrase B」

=

> "Phrase B in addition to Phrase A"